# Using templates in classes

Tags: c++, templates

I used a template within a c++ class. However, when I try to call a function using a template from another function in the class, I get an error.
What should I fix?

```
void MyClass::Display()
{
    cout << "sum :   ";
    cout << setw(30) <<Add();
}
template <typename T>
T MyClass::Add()
{
    T sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        sum += y[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

In this way, an error occurs in add() of the display part

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the full error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Add(). But you do not specify the template argument for `Add()` you want to use.

You can specify it by: `Add<*type*>()`